# JAVAFX - tree happening

Tags: menu, javafx, tree

I have a good working JavaFX tree, with menus on it.

```
>File 
  new file
  open file
  .........
```

I have a listener, which listens every change and reacts something if the user click on an item.

It is working properly:

```
   public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {

    TreeItem<String> selectedItem = (TreeItem<String>) newValue;

                     String actualmenu;
        actualmenu = selectedItem.getValue();

        if ("New Project".equals(actualmenu)){
         // I make a new scene...
        }
```

But my only problem is that this Treemenu shows the "submenus", only if I click on the little Triangle which is next to the menu name (>File)

I would like to set the "File" menuitem, to show it's submenus if I click to itself, not just the triangle. It would be something this:

```
 public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue,
            Object newValue) {

    TreeItem<String> selectedItem = (TreeItem<String>) newValue;


                     String actualmenu;
        actualmenu = selectedItem.getValue();

        if ("File".equals(actualmenu)){
         // open your subs in the tree, show me your submenus! What do I have to write here?
        }
```

Does anyone have idea what to write overthere?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but are you looking for `selectedItem.setExpanded(true);`?

Comment: James, it is exactly what I was looking for. :) Thank for the help - again. If you write your comment to an answer, I give the green accept!